# Dynamic Chart using JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have an array of 100,000 samples all of double type. I want to display or plot this array so that I get a moving chart/ plot (dynamic) instead of displaying it at once. Can anyone help me out. In plot ee[] and y[] is obtained after some processing.

```
private byte[] FileR(String filename) {
    byte[] data = null;
    AudioInputStream ais;
    try {
        File fileIn = new File(filename);
        if (fileIn.exists()) {
            ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(fileIn);
            data = new byte[ais.available()];
            ais.read(data);
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not read " + filename);
    }
    return data;
}

private byte[] Capture(double t) throws LineUnavailableException {
    AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(48000, 16, 2, true, false);
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
    line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    line.open(format);
    line.open();
    int size = (int) (line.getBufferSize() * t);
    byte[] b = new byte[size];
    line.start();
    line.read(b, 0, size);
    return b;
}

private void plot(double[] ee, double[] y) {
    XYSeries see = new XYSeries("Filtered");
    for (int i = 0; i < ee.length; i++) {
        see.add(i, ee[i]);
    }
    XYSeriesCollection cee = new XYSeriesCollection();
    cee.addSeries(see);
    XYItemRenderer ree = new StandardXYItemRenderer();
    NumberAxis rangeAxisee = new NumberAxis("Filtered");
    XYPlot subplot1 = new XYPlot(cee, null, rangeAxisee, ree);
    subplot1.setRangeAxisLocation(AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_LEFT);
    XYSeries sy = new XYSeries("Noisy");
    for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        sy.add(i, y[i]);
    }
    XYSeriesCollection cy = new XYSeriesCollection();
    cy.addSeries(sy);
    XYItemRenderer ry = new StandardXYItemRenderer();
    NumberAxis rangeAxisy = new NumberAxis("Noisy");
    XYPlot subplot2 = new XYPlot(cy, null, rangeAxisy, ry);
    subplot2.setRangeAxisLocation(AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_LEFT);
    CombinedDomainXYPlot plot = new CombinedDomainXYPlot(new NumberAxis("Domain"));
    plot.setGap(10.0);
    plot.add(subplot1);
    plot.add(subplot2);
    plot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.VERTICAL);
    JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Adaptive Filter", JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, true);
    panel = new ChartPanel(chart, true, true, true, false, true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(750, 500);
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean? You mean it changes at runtime? an animation?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for one of the approaches shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5048852/230513).

Comment: Oliver Watkins, probably you have got my question. can you help me out.

Comment: @OliverWatkins may not see your response unless you use the `@` sign. In the interim, please edit your question to clarify how it differs form this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5048852/230513).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a **thread** where all this data is coming from. For example from your backend. Then, every time there is a new set of data for the chart you will need to update the chart via the **Event Dispatch Thread**. If your chart data is coming in regular intervals it is fairly easy (ie. pull), however if it is push (ie. the data is more random), and can get a little more tricky.

Remove all the GUI creation out of the plot method :

```
JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Adaptive Filter", JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, true);
panel = new ChartPanel(chart, true, true, true, false, true);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(750, 500);
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

This only needs to be called once. The **plot** method will be called every time new data comes.

Here is a simple approach :

```
public void startCharting() {

    final MySoundCard card = new MySoundCard();
    final MyJFreeChart chart = new MyJFreeChart();

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {

                int[] i = card.FileR();


                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        chart.plot();
                    }

                });


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    };

    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
}
```

A thread calls your datasource every second and then updates the chart. The updates are invoked in the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: The data (Array of samples) received  from an audio file or captured from the sound card. Now I want to display that one in a moving fashion (dynamic - not in time series) instead of displaying in one go. If possible exemplify please.

Comment: Firstly how is your data coming into your application. Are you calling a method? Or is the data being captured somehow in your application?

Comment: @AbdulBaseerBuriro I added some code which should give you an idea.

Comment: Data is coming through a method call. One method is to get a data from a file and second gets from the card. This is based on user's selection.

Comment: @AbdulBaseerBuriro you should paste some code in your question. Can't really help you much more than that.